# Comparing infinite values

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For the equation

$$\frac{\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow 0^+}\int_n^1\frac1x\;dx}{\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac1x} = a$$

[(original handwritten equation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0nDy.jpg)

does $a$ have a finite value?

Comment: The meaning of the left side is undefined. You'd actually have to be explicit about what limit you are taking that has this form...

Comment: And that limit is $1$, @ForgotALot

Comment: I nervously deleted my comment to which Thomas Andrews responded, but was proposing something like $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\int_{1/n}^1 dx/x)/(\sum_{x=1}^n 1/x)$.  It just doesn't seem meaningful to me.

Comment: I actually have good reason to believe that the answer is one

Comment: @ samarbarrett : as everybody said, what you wrote is undefined : $\infty / \infty$. did you mean $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{dx}{x}}{\sum_{n=1}^{1/\epsilon} \frac{1}{n}}$$ ?

Comment: In the original handwritten the sum is $\sum_{n=1}$. In any case the expression is undefined.

Comment: user9152009 yes that is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator of your fraction can be written as 
$$ \lim _{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n\frac1r $$
Which can be made a Riemann sum as:
$$\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{r=1} \frac{1}{r/n}$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{1}{x}dx$$
Any similarities with the numerator?

Comment: is there somewhere I can find more information about this?

Comment: Just google Riemann sums, and you'll find plenty of stuff

Answer (score 1):

What you have written, does not make sense:

> $$\int_0^1{ \frac{dx}{x}}$$ is undefined: $ln(x)$ is not defined when $x = 0$.

Comment: This is not the whole expression under investigation (ps I did not downvote)

Comment: @poirot this was the original post by OP.

Comment: In that case you don't deserve a downvote!

Comment: @poirot Thanks!